# How can i deploy Next JS?

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, build, tailwind-css

I created my first Next JS project with Tailwind and wanted to build it with "next build".
Then it created a folder ".next", but there is not a single .html file.

I come from the Angular world and there it simply works with "ng build".

I'm on All Inkl for my projects and of course it can't read the Next JS files.

All files in my project are .js files

How can I make it run on my server like with Angular projects?

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,}
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I've tried everything Google and ChatGPT have suggested, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The correct command is `npm run build`. It worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `next start`.

If you bootstrapped your project with `create-next-app` then you should have a `start` script in your `package.json`, so should able to run either of these (depending on your package manager):

- `npm start`
- `pnpm start`
- `yarn start`

Comment: watch my last answer. there are 2 pictures

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to look for out dir. You will find the exported static file there.

Answer (score -2):

Thats my out folder and my package.json [folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJc5g.png)

And here is the error from the console: [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VHvk.png)

I have put two screenshots here.
One shows the folders and the other shows the errors in the console.

I have already tried npm update. I deleted the .next folder and regenerated it with next build. but all without success.

Maybe someone can access it remotely and have a look

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to find your build errors, it says `Export encountered errors on following paths`

Comment: but how? is my folder structure wrong? I can't figure it out